# php -v still shows old version

Tags: apt, server, php, nginx

So I am trying to updated from 7.1.1 to 7.1.17. I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1
```

and got `7.1.17-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1` but when I run

```
php -v
```

in the terminal I get `PHP 7.1.1-1+deb.sury.org`. I am using digital ocean configured with nginx. I've restarted the server and restarted nginx, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1 php7.1-common
```

It is now updated to the latest version.